# cypher variables value empty during the query

Tags: variables, return-value, cypher

I'am writing a cypher query which is :

```
 MATCH (user:User{email: "mail@mail.com"} )-[:friendsWith]->(friend:User) ,   (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe)
WHERE not (friend.email = "mail@mail.com")
set rec.ifLiked = "false"
with rec
match (m:Recipe {name:"myName"})
return rec
```

it returns nothing (0 nodes)

if I remove the line :

```
match (m:Recipe {name:"same"})
```

it returns the wanted values , what's wrong ??!! , the line that I added mustn't change the value of rec !!!

Comment: Why would you do this?  Instead of just saying `with rec` and doing another match, why don't you return `rec` immediately without the extra match?  It would solve your problem and be a simpler query.

Comment: I want to another significant thing instead of match (m:Recipe {name:"myName"}) , but I didn't put for sake of simpleness :D

Comment: Well I think it's not working because `rec` is not implicated anywhere in your match.

Comment: yes it is if you go to right a little bit :P   ,,, (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe)

Comment: That's in the **first** match.  In the second match, `rec` isn't mentioned.

Comment: so it's value deleted ? , wait , every match I make deletes the last one ?

Comment: I tried to put the second match with the first match like :
 MATCH (user:User{email: "mail@mail.com"} )-[:friendsWith]->(friend:User) ,   (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe) , (m:Recipe {name:"myName"}) 
and I removed the : with rec , it gave me the same results , when I remove this little (m:Recipe {name:"myName"})  everything goes well , am getting crazy !

Comment: No, I think you've hit on a strange edge case, and you're not providing the whole real query so it's hard to tell.  But it would sorta make sense if `RETURN` could only return things that were mentioned in `MATCH` or `START`.  In any case, this query construction doesn't make much sense.  If you don't need to mention `rec` in `MATCH`, then why construct the query this way?  If you did mention `rec` in `MATCH`, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: what I need is to get recipes of friends of user , and for every recipe I need to set the property ifLiked to true (if the user liked it (make likeRecipe reaction ) ) ,  or false if the user doesn't like the recipe that's all. so what am I doing is getting all the user's friends recipes  , and set the value of ifLiked to false , then (in the second match ) I want to get the recipes that the user likes , and set the ifLiked to true.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to bring a variable with you via the `WITH` clause, but then not mention it in the subsequent query, so you should reformulate your query.

If all you want to return is `rec`, the easier way is this:

```
 MATCH (user:User{email: "mail@mail.com"} )-[:friendsWith]->(friend:User) ,   (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe)
WHERE not (friend.email = "mail@mail.com")
set rec.ifLiked = "false"
RETURN rec;
```

Another option:

```
MATCH (user:User{email: "mail@mail.com"} )-[:friendsWith]->(friend:User) ,   (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe)
WHERE not (friend.email = "mail@mail.com")
set rec.ifLiked = "false"
WITH rec
MATCH rec, (m:Recipe {name:"myName"})
RETURN rec;
```

That will work, but note the extra match on `m:Recipe` still doesn't make sense, because it's not part of `RETURN` and also not part of any later `SET` clause.

Comment: this is the whole query
MATCH (user:User{email: "mail@mail.com"} )-[:friendsWith]->(friend:User) ,   (friend:User)-[:MadeRecipe]->(rec:Recipe)
WHERE not (friend.email = "mail@mail.com")
set rec.ifLiked = "false"
with rec , user
match (user)-[:likeRecipe]->(likedRecipe:Recipe)
set likedRecipe.ifLiked = "true"
return rec

Comment: and I tried your query it gave me the same results as mine

Comment: You should do this as two separate queries.  Your two matches are completely unrelated to one another.

Comment: the problem that this is part of social network , so it's very expensive to do two queries , but thank you any way :D

Comment: I don't follow "it's expensive to do two queries".  You *are* doing two queries worth of work, you're just combining them into one syntactic query.